# How to auto close DarkTable when loading RAW files via Gimp script-fu?

Tags: gimp, script-fu

If invoking Gimp script-fu from a batch file and passing a RAW file (.dng) as the input filename, DarkTable opens upon executing the command `(gimp-file-load RUN-NONINTERACTIVE filename filename)`. The windows has to be closed interactivly for script-fu to continue. Is there a parameter, a setting or a switch somewhere to automatically close and exit DarkTable?

Comment: To automatically close **after doing what?**. The whole purpose of these plugins is to let the user do specific processing before passing the picture to Gimp. You can run the demosaicing in a separate app before calling Gimp on the demosaiced files (TIFF or else). Also, demosaicing apps can usually apply a "recipe" in batch mode on several files.

Comment: @xenoid I don't do anything in that window. I installed DarkTable because Gimp requires it to open a RAW file. As soon as Gimp launches DarkTable, I immediately close it without doing anything and Gimp then opens the file.

Comment: That's the point. Shooting RAW serves little purpose if the demosaicing is all automated, it can just as well be done in-camera. And, there are scriptable ways to transform a RAW into a file format that Gimp will open non-interactively.

Comment: @xenoid I would appreciate a litte more info on that.

Comment: [nufraw-batch](https://man.archlinux.org/man/community/gimp-nufraw/nufraw.1.en) for instance.

Comment: nufraw-batch doesn't work under windows 10, because there are libraries missing. But dcdraw does the job and it is included in ImageMagick. And I found some great IM scripts for Windows (https://im.snibgo.com/) comparable to Fred's. These taught me the importance of demosaicing.